# running multiple bash commands with subprocess

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

If I run `echo a; echo b` in bash the result will be that both commands are run. However if I use subprocess then the first command is run, printing out the whole of the rest of the line.
The code below echos `a; echo b` instead of `a b`, how do I get it to run both commands?

```
import subprocess, shlex
def subprocess_cmd(command):
    process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    proc_stdout = process.communicate()[0].strip() 
    print proc_stdout

subprocess_cmd("echo a; echo b")
```

Comment: related: Here's [how to run multiple shell commands (and optionally capture their output) concurrently](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23616229/4279)

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You have to use shell=True in subprocess and no shlex.split:

```py
import subprocess

command = "echo a; echo b"

ret = subprocess.run(command, capture_output=True, shell=True)

# before Python 3.7:
# ret = subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

print(ret.stdout.decode())
```

returns:

```
a
b
```

Comment: Ah I see, I had `shell=True` tested but command.split() was breaking it (list). Also to note to other people reading, using `shell=True` is a security hazard, make sure you trust the input.

Comment: You cannot use `command.split()` with `shell=True`. Actually the argument of `subprocess.Popen` with `shell=True` must be a string and not a list.

Comment: I found this to be a bit simpler and didn't have the garbling of the output:     def do_shell(self, command):
        self.proc=subprocess.Popen(command,shell=True)
        self.proc.wait()

Comment: @Ravichandra: notice: `bash` in the title. On Windows, you probably want `echo a & echo b` command instead.

Comment: Your result runs `/bin/sh`, not `/bin/bash`. Add `executable='/bin/bash'` to the `Popen()` args to get a bash shell.

Comment: On windows this does not work, it returns "a; echo b"

Comment: @Milan, on windows, the default shell is batch, which does not honor ';' as a separator.

Answer (score 32):

I just stumbled on a situation where I needed to run a bunch of lines of bash code (not separated with semicolons) from within python. In this scenario the proposed solutions do not help. One approach would be to save a file and then run it with `Popen`, but it wasn't possible in my situation.

What I ended up doing is something like:

```
commands = '''
echo "a"
echo "b"
echo "c"
echo "d"
'''

process = subprocess.Popen('/bin/bash', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=true)
out, err = process.communicate(commands)
print(out)
```

So I first create the child bash process and after I tell it what to execute. This approach removes the limitations of passing the command directly to the `Popen` constructor.

The `text=True` addition is required for Python 3.

Comment: `subprocess.check_output(commands, shell=True)` works just fine. If there are bash-isms in commands then pass `executable='/bin/bash'`.

Comment: For Python 3 you might want to use: `out, err = process.communicate(commands.encode('utf-8'))` and `print(out.decode('utf-8'))`

Comment: If the commands are `;` separated you might also want to add `shell=True` to the `subprocess.Popen()` line.

Comment: Modern Python should use `subprocess.run(commands, shell=True)`. Like the `Popen` documentation already tells you, avoid it when you can, such as when all you want to do is run a subprocess and wait for it to finish.

Answer (score 21):

Join commands with "&&".

```
os.system('echo a > outputa.txt && echo b > outputb.txt')
```

Comment: The second command would not run if the first command has an error.   I would say use an ; instead.

Comment: The important part here is to use `os.system()` instead of `subprocess`.

Comment: os.system is not a substitute for subprocess.
os.system cannot do all the things that subprocess does.

Comment: Maybe not, but it can `echo` just fine.

Comment: subprocess is preferred to os.system, but no one has given an answer that works with subprocess and shell=False (or analogous).

Answer (score 4):

If you're only running the commands in one shot then you can just use [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) convenience function:

```
def subprocess_cmd(command):
    output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
    print output
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> command = "echo a; echo b"
>>> shlex.split(command);
    ['echo', 'a; echo', 'b']
```

so, the problem is shlex module do not handle ";"

Comment: command.split() gives `['echo', 'a;', 'echo', 'b']` and also fails.
`

Comment: @bougui is right. Set "shell=True", the first argument of Popen need a command string like "echo a;echo b". and without "shell=True" the first argument of Popen should be a list, like:["echo","a"]

Answer (score 1):

Got errors like when I used capture_output=True

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'capture_output'
```

After made changes like as below and its works fine

```
import subprocess

command = '''ls'''

result = subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)

print(result.stdout.splitlines())
```

Comment: `capture_output` was only introduced in Python 3.7, which is quite old already, but apparently yours is older still.

Comment: (The `shell=True` is useless here; `ls` runs fine without a shell, though nominally you should then pass the command as a list `["ls"]`.)

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess
cmd = "vsish -e ls /vmkModules/lsom/disks/  | cut -d '/' -f 1  | while read diskID  ; do echo $diskID; vsish -e cat /vmkModules/lsom/disks/$diskID/virstoStats | grep -iE 'Delete pending |trims currently queued' ;  echo '====================' ;done ;"


def subprocess_cmd(command):
    process = subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    proc_stdout = process.communicate()[0].strip()
    for line in proc_stdout.decode().split('\n'):
        print (line)

subprocess_cmd(cmd)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide an explanation as to how the code you provided answers the original question.

Comment: Run commends with pipe(|)