# subprocess.Popen using relative paths

Tags: python, path, subprocess, popen, cwd

The [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) for Popen mention that you can't specify your executable path relative to the 'change working directory' kwarg.

> If `cwd` is not None, the child’s current directory will be changed to
> `cwd` before it is executed. **Note that this directory is not
> considered when searching the executable, so you can’t specify the
> program’s path relative to `cwd`.**

But python's behaviour on my system seems to directly contradict this claim:

```
/tmp$ mkdir a
/tmp$ cp /bin/ls /tmp/a/my_ls
/tmp$ mkdir b
/tmp$ touch /tmp/b/potato
/tmp$ cd /home/wim
~$ python
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Sep 19 2013, 13:48:49) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from subprocess import check_output
>>> check_output(['../a/my_ls'], cwd='/tmp/b')
'potato\n'
>>> check_output(['../a/my_ls'])
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Is using relative paths to `cwd` something that is platform dependent and shouldn't be relied upon?  Or is this a documentation bug?

(this question spawns from a comment by glglgl [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21406887/674039#comment32299912_21407005))

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, this is platform dependant.

On POSIX systems, the process is forked and in the child process a `os.chdir(cwd)` is executed before executing the executable.

On Windows however, the [`CreateProcess()` API call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is used and `cwd` is passed in as the `lpCurrentDirectory` parameter.  No directory change takes place, and the `CreateProcess()` call does *not* consult that parameter when looking for the `lpApplicationName` to execute.

To keep your application cross-platform, you should not rely on the current working directory to be changed when looking up the executable.