# How can I write text into a file using a subprocess inside a Python script?

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I want to run a script using a subprocess inside a main script which would give a few lines of text as a result and then copy the results to a text file. I am using Python 2.7.

The folder where I want to run the secondary script is a different one from the folder where the main script is located, so I am following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34539434/3828640) where it is explained how to do this.

My code looks like the following:

```
import subprocess

if __name__=="__main__":
    subprocess.check_call(['top > test.txt'], cwd=newdirectory)
```

In this case I am just using top as an example of what I want to do. If I write `top > test.txt`in my terminal I get a text file called test.txt with the output of top at the moment of execution of the command.

But if I run the code that I posted above I get an error. I have also tried to use something like:

```
import subprocess

if __name__=="__main__":
    subprocess.check_call(['top', '> test.txt'], cwd=newdirectory)
```

But this doesn't give anything either (which makes sense as `>test.txt` is not an argument for the top command.

How can I write the output of the script (or in this case top) to the file test.txt in the new directory?

Comment: Not 100%, but I think you just have to hand `shell=True` to `check_call`.

Comment: If you put `shell=True`, in case of top, it will block your terminal.

Comment: You can't just use python for your file-reading and writing? Alternatively, a bash script instead of python?