# SVN update programatically - python

Tags: python, svn, process, tortoisesvn, checkout

I want to call `'svn update'` programmatically using `Python`

I have implemented `svn-checkout` using the below code and is it is working fine.

```
cmd = svn_path + ' co ' + repopath + ' ' + directory_path

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

For check-out used `co` command but, couldn't find commands for update the svn repository.

Please help to find the update command.

Comment: I don't have SVN set up on my machine to test...
Perhaps you should just use `up`? Taken from [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.update.html)

Comment: You could try without python first. `svn update` (or `svn up`, just the same shorter) if you are in the right directory, or `svn up directory_path` from anywhere, either should work. Then just the same from python.

Answer (score 0):

These two posts helped me to solve this,

https://www.guyrutenberg.com/2007/10/29/creating-local-svn-repository-home-repository/comment-page-1/

[Subprocess changing directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406887/subprocess-changing-directory/21406995)

```
cmd = svn_path + ' update'
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,cwd="working direcroty path", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```