# Passing command from python file to shell script (Linux)

Tags: python, shell, module, sh

I edited this post so that i could give more info about the goal I am trying to achieve.
basically I want to be able to open VSCode in a directory that I can input inside a python file I am running trhough a shell command i created.
So what I need is for the python file to ask me for the name of the folder I want to open, pass that information to the terminal so that it can then cd into that folder and open vscode automatically.
I tried with os.system() that is, as I read, one of the ways I can achieve that goal.
The problem is that if I use standard commands like os.system('date') or os.system('code') it works without any problem.
If I try to use os.system(cd /directory/) nothing happens.
As suggested I also tryied with `subprocess.call(["cd", "/home/simon/Desktop"])` but the terminal gives me the error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cd'`
I am going to include both the python file:

```
import os, subprocess

PATH = "/home/simon/Linux_Storage/Projects"


def main():

    print("\n")
    print("********************")
    for folder in os.listdir(PATH):
        print(folder)
    print("********************")
    project = input("Choose project: ")
    print("\n")

    folders = os.listdir(PATH)
    while project:
        if project in folders:
            break
        else:
            print("Project doesn't exist.")
            project = input("Choose project: ")

    os.system(f"cd /home/simon/Linux_Storage/Projects/{project}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and the shell script (maybe I should change something here):

```
function open() {
    python3 .open.py
    code .
}
```

Comment: What your ultimate end-goal here? The Python-script will launch it's own process when you start it, so it cannot (easily) integrate with your your VTY. When you're calling `os.system` you aren't calling the OS through your own terminal, it's calling the OS directly with it's own calls.

Comment: If you just want to have easy access to some commands, then a [bash-alias](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias) might be what you're after instead.

Comment: basically I need to change the terminal directory from the python file so that I can open VSCode directly from that directory.
I am launching the python file through a custom shell command that I created.

Comment: Finally I found the solution. I looked for it for like 4 days without finding anything! Thank you very much! maybe add this as an answer so it can be useful in the future :)!

Answer (score 0):

Use os.chdir() instead.
Running that command spawns a child with that command.

Also answered here
[Subprocess changing directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406887/subprocess-changing-directory)

Comment: doesn't os.chdir change the directory only for the python file?
I've tried but it doesn't do what I need T.T

Comment: probably need more information on what you are trying to achieve :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `os.chdir()` instead of `os.system('cd /home/simon/Desktop')`

```
#change directory
os.chdir('/home/simon/Desktop') 

#get current path
os.getcwd()

#execute script 
exec(open('path/to/yourfile.py').read())

#then change the path back to the current working directory
```