# How to handle subprocess.run() error/exception

Tags: python, subprocess, cd

How do I handle a `subprocess.run()` error in Python? For example, I want to run `cd + UserInput` with `subprocess.run()`. What if the user types in a directory name which does not exist? How do I handle this type of error?

Comment: Running `cd` in `subprocess.run()` is a bad idea. Look at using the `cwd=` kyword parameter to `run()` instead, then you can catch `FileNotFoundError` if the diectory doesn't exist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subprocess changing directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406887/subprocess-changing-directory)

Comment: You probably want to use [`os.chdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir). There is no point in starting a process just to change its own directory and immediately exit...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way running `cd` in a subprocess is useful. The subprocess will change its own directory and then immediately exit, leaving no observable change in the parent process or anywhere else.

For the same reason, there is no binary command named `cd` on most systems; the `cd` command is a shell built-in.

Generally, if you run `subprocess.run()` without the `check=True` keyword argument, any error within the subprocess will simply be ignored. So if `/bin/cd` or a similar command existed, you could run

```
# purely theoretical, and utterly useless
subprocess.run(['cd', UserInput])
```

and simply not know whether it did anything or not.

If you do supply `check=True`, the exception you need to trap is [`CalledProcessError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CalledProcessError):

```
try:
    # pointless code as such; see explanation above
    subprocess.run(['cd', UserInput], check=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    print('Directory name %s misspelled, or you lack the permissions' % UserInput)
```

But even more fundamentally, allowing users to prod the system by running arbitrary unchecked input in a subprocess is a horrible idea. (Allowing users to run arbitrary shell script with `shell=True` is a *monumentally, catastrophically* horrible idea, so let's not even go there. Maybe see [Actual meaning of `shell=True` in `subprocess`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess))

A somewhat more secure approach is to run the subprocess with a `cwd=` keyword argument.

```
# also vaguely pointless
subprocess.run(['true'], cwd=UserInput)
```

In this case, you can expect a regular `FileNotFoundError` if the directory does not exist, or a `PermissionError` if you lack the privileges.

You should probably still add `check=True` and be prepared to handle any resulting exception, unless you specifically don't care whether the subprocess succeeded. (There are actually cases where this makes sense, like when you `grep` for something but are fine with it not finding any matches, which raises an error if you use `check=True`.)

Perhaps see also [Running Bash commands in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python/51950538#51950538)

Answer (score 4):

As @match has mentioned, you can't run `cd` as a subprocess, because `cd` isn't a program, it's a shell built-in command.

But if you're asking about any subprocess failures, besides `cd`:

```py
try:
    subprocess.run(command_that_might_not_exist)  # like ['abcd']
except Exception:
    # handle the error
```

```py
result = subprocess.run(command_that_might_fail)  # like ['ls', 'abcd/']
if result.returncode != 0:
    # handle the error
```

Comment: *"you can't run cd as a subprocess, because cd isn't a program, it's a shell built-in command."* - you can run `subprocess.run("cd", shell=True)`, but that would just be pointless...

Comment: The only way the first example can fail is if the operating system can't find or can't execute `command_that_might_not_exist`

Comment: @tripleee, you are correct. `command_that_might_fail` is more common

Comment: You should probably use a more specific trap in the `except` clause than the very generic `Exception`. This is equivalent to a bare `except`, which (as you probably already know) is a bad idea: [What is wrong with using a bare `except`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54948548/what-is-wrong-with-using-a-bare-except)