Unable to execute batch file by Python program
I have a WORKING batch file that I want to execute by my Python program. here is the portion of program related to that task:
def execute_batch_file(self):
    batch_file_path = r'C:\Users\UTENTE\Desktop\Programmi compilati Python\OP10\prova.bat'
    subprocess.Popen(batch_file_path, shell=True)

when I run the program I get the error message "Cannot open exaple.prn for reading".
Again, if I execute the batch file manually I have no issue whatsoever. It does work fine. When I run it by my program I get the message above.
For info, the batch file lunches an "lpr" command for a ".prn" file to be printed.
Any clue about the issue?
Thanks alot.

Add the full path to the print file in your batch script.

Also do some research about "current working directory" and how that is relevant for relative paths, which is almost certainly the issue you're facing (it's a valid assumption, but you should've at least included the line related to the prn file, we should not be forced to make guesses).

Well, apparently your batch file is not WORKING as well as you expected. Also learn about minimal reproducible examples so we don't have to guess.

@Nico The usage of "%~dp0exaple.prn" instead of just exaple.prn would have solved the problem too. %~dp0 is drive and path of argument 0 which is the batch file name argument string. %~dp0 expands therefore to full directory path of the batch file always ending with a backslash which is concatenated with the file name expected in the batch file directory and not in the current working directory.

add the cwd keyword argument to subprocess.Popen and pass bat file directory to it.
def execute_batch_file(self):
    batch_file_path = r'C:\Users\UTENTE\Desktop\Programmi compilati Python\OP10\prova.bat';
    
    # get bat file dir and name
    batch_file_name = os.path.basename(batch_file_path)
    batch_file_dir = os.path.dirname(batch_file_path)


    subprocess.Popen(batch_file_name, cwd=batch_file_dir, shell=True)

don't forget to import os
I learnt from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21406995/21962459
