# How to run multiple commands synchronously from one subprocess.Popen command?

Tags: python, subprocess, python-3.5, python-2.6

Is it possible to execute an arbitrary number of commands in sequence using the same subprocess command?

I need each command to wait for the previous one to complete before executing and I need them all to be executed in the same session/shell. I also need this to work in Python 2.6, Python 3.5. I also need the subprocess command to work in Linux, Windows and macOS (which is why I'm just using `echo` commands as examples here).

See **non-working** code below:

```
import sys
import subprocess

cmds = ['echo start', 'echo mid', 'echo end']

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd=tuple([item for item in cmds]),
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
    sys.stdout.flush()
    print(">>> " + line.rstrip())
```

If this is not possible, which approach should I take in order to execute my commands in synchronous sequence within the same session/shell?

Comment: Why not using three Popen in sequence?

Comment: How about running cmd1, cmd2, cmd3 in separate execution of Popen?

Comment: @RiccardoPetraglia I edited my question since it involves an arbitrary number of commands.

Comment: @AlokThakur if I execute one Popen per cmd, they will be executed in their own sessions. I need them all to be executed in the same session. I'm editing my question to include that info now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [running multiple bash commands with subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17742789/running-multiple-bash-commands-with-subprocess)

Answer (score 16):

If you want to execute many commands one after the other in the same *session/shell*, you must start a shell and feed it with all the commands, one at a time followed by a new line, and close the pipe at the end. It makes sense if some commands are not true processes but shell commands that could for example change the shell environment.

Example using Python 2.7 under Windows:

```
encoding = 'latin1'
p = subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe', stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
             stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
for cmd in cmds:
    p.stdin.write(cmd + "\n")
p.stdin.close()
print p.stdout.read()
```

To have this code run under Linux, you would have to replace `cmd.exe` with `/bin/bash` and probably change the encoding to utf8.

For Python 3, you would have to encode the commands and probably decode their output, and to use parentheses with print.

Beware: this can only work for little output. If there was enough output to fill the pipe buffer before closing the stdin pipe, this code would deadlock. A more robust way would be to have a second thread to read the output of the commands to avoid that problem.

Answer (score 11):

This is similar to the answer posted by Serge Ballesta, but not quite.  Use his for asynchronous execution, where you don't care about the results.  Use mine for synchronous processing and result gathering.  Like his answer, I'm showing the Windows solution here - run a bash process in Linux rather than cmd in Windows.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
process = Popen( "cmd.exe", shell=False, universal_newlines=True,
                  stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE )                             
out, err = process.communicate( commands )
```

**USAGE DETAILS:** The `commands` argument being passed here to the `process.communicate` method is a **newline delimited** string.  If, for example you just read a batch file contents into a string, you could run it this way because it would already have the newlines.

**Important**: your string must end in a newline `"\n"`.  If it does not, that final command will fail to execute.  Just like if you typed it into your command prompt but didn't hit `enter` at the end.  You will however see a mysterious `More?` line in the end of the stdout returned.  (that's the cause if you encounter this).

`process.communicate` runs synchronously by definition, and returns the stdout and stderr messages (if you directed them to `subprocess.PIPE` in your Popen constructor).

When you create a `cmd.exe` process in this way, and pass a string to it, the results will be exactly like if you were to open a command prompt window and entered commands into.  And I mean that quite literally.  If you test this, you will see that the stdout which is returned contains your commands.  (It does NOT matter if you include an `@echo off` like if executing a batch file).

Tips for those who care about "clean" stdout results:

- `@echo off` will not suppress your commands from appearing in this returned string, but it does remove extra newlines that find their way in there otherwise.  (universal_newlines=True strips an another set of those)
- Including an `@` symbol prefix to your commands allows them to still execute.  In a "normal" batch process that's the line-by-line way to "hide" your commands.  In this context, it's a safe an easy marker by which you can find stdout lines you want to remove. (if one were so inclined)
- The cmd.exe "header" will appear in your output (which says the version of Windows etc.).  Since you probably want to start your set of commands with `@echo off`, to cut out the extra newlines, that is also a great way to find where the header lines stopped and your commands/results began.

Finally, to address concerns about "large" output filling the pipes and causing you problems - first I think you need a HUGE amount of data coming back for that to be an issue - more than most people will encounter in their use cases.  Second, if it really is a concern just open a file for writing and pass that file handle (the reference to the file object) to stdout/err instead of `PIPE`.  Then, do whatever you want with the file you've created.

Comment: raise ValueError("Cannot send input after starting communication") do not work

Comment: Please clarify what you are saying or asking.  If you encountered this exception, and would like help, please say what OS you are using, the version of Python, and ideally share your exact code.

Comment: For python 3, you might need to specify `encoding='utf8'` or similar as a parameter of subprocess for this to work

Answer (score 4):

One possible solution, looks like its running in same shell:

```
subprocess.Popen('echo start;echo mid;echo end', shell=True)
```

Note - If you pass your command as a string then shell has to be True
Note - This is working on linux only, you may have to find something similar way out on windows.

Hope it will help.

From python doc -

> On Unix with shell=True, the shell defaults to /bin/sh. If args is a
>   string, the string specifies the command to execute through the shell.
>   This means that the string must be formatted exactly as it would be
>   when typed at the shell prompt.

Comment: Yes, using shell=True is not a preferable way

Comment: Apparently, at least in python 2.7 this one works also on windows:  >On Windows with shell=True, the COMSPEC environment variable specifies the default shell. The only time you need to specify shell=True on Windows is when the command you wish to execute is built into the shell (e.g. dir or copy). You do not need shell=True to run a batch file or console-based executable.<

Comment: @AlokThakur will all the above 3 commands dump their output on `STDOUT` in serialized fashion or there is a possibility of getting a jumbled output.

Comment: Although shell=True is not preferable on documentation, in some special cases (e.g. if you want to execute git push from jupyter notebook with a non-default key), this turns out to be the only solution. So one big THANK YOU, @AlokThakur.

Comment: it is not preferable when there is a risk of injection through unsanitized data. For the given question it is best possible solution

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function (and main to run it) that I use. I would say that you can use it for your problem. And it is flexible.

```
# processJobsInAList.py
# 2016-09-27   7:00:00 AM   Central Daylight Time 

import win32process, win32event

def CreateMyProcess2(cmd):
    ''' create process width no window that runs a command with arguments
    and returns the process handle'''
    si   = win32process.STARTUPINFO()
    info = win32process.CreateProcess(
        None,      # AppName
        cmd,       # Command line
        None,      # Process Security
        None,      # Thread Security
        0,         # inherit Handles?
        win32process.NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
        None,      # New environment
        None,      # Current directory
        si)        # startup info
    # info is tuple (hProcess, hThread, processId, threadId)
    return info[0]

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    ''' create/run a process for each list element in "cmds"
    output may be out of order because processes run concurrently '''

    cmds=["echo my","echo heart","echo belongs","echo to","echo daddy"]
    handles    = []
    for i in range(len(cmds)):
        cmd    = 'cmd /c ' + cmds[i]
        handle = CreateMyProcess2(cmd)
        handles.append(handle)

    rc = win32event.WaitForMultipleObjects( handles, 1, -1)  # 1 wait for all, -1 wait infinite
    print 'return code ',rc
```

output:
heart
my
belongs
to
daddy
return code  0

UPDATE: If you want to run the same process, which will serialize things for you:
1) Remove line:  handles.append(handle)
2) Substitute the variable "handle" in place of the list "handles" on the "WaitFor" line
3) Substitute WaitForSingleObject in place of WaitForMultipleObjects

Answer (score 1):

This one works in python 2.7 and should work also in windows. Probably some small refinement is needed for python >3.

The produced output is (using date and sleep it is easy to see that the commands are executed in row):

```
>>>Die Sep 27 12:47:52 CEST 2016
>>>
>>>Die Sep 27 12:47:54 CEST 2016
```

As you see the commands are executed in a row.

```
    import sys
    import subprocess
    import shlex

    cmds = ['date', 'sleep 2', 'date']

    cmds = [shlex.split(x) for x in cmds]

    outputs =[]
    for cmd in cmds:
        outputs.append(subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT).communicate())


    for line in outputs:
        print ">>>" + line[0].strip()
```

#### This is what I obtain merging with @Marichyasana answer:

```
import sys
import os


def run_win_cmds(cmds):

    @Marichyasana code (+/-)

def run_unix_cmds(cmds):

    import subprocess
    import shlex


    cmds = [shlex.split(x) for x in cmds]

    outputs =[]
    for cmd in cmds:
        outputs.append(subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT).communicate())


    rc = ''
    for line in outputs:
        rc +=  line[0].strip()+'\n'

    return rc


cmds = ['date', 'sleep 2', 'date']

if os.name == 'nt':
     run_win_cmds(cmds)
elif os.name == 'posix':
    run_unix_cmds(cmds)
```

Ask is this one do not fit your needs! ;)

Comment: This looks like it could work! But on Windows, I'm getting ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "seq_test.py", line 12, in <module>
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT).communicate())
  File "c:\python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "c:\python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified``` - any idea why? (I replaced the commands with echo commands as per my initial question so those commands can run in Windows)

Comment: Did you try your commands with a simple Popen/communicate on windows? It could be that cmds must be a string (reading the last part of the subprocess documentation)

Comment: This doesn't look it is executing the commands within the same process, which is a fundamental component to this question.

Comment: The question is very clear about this point.  It's what the question is all about it's core.  Both of your code samples execute commands in separate sub processes, not the same one.  Look at Serge Ballesta's answer, where he pipes in multiple commands to the same shell session.  The results of that would be radically different, and answers the question.  As an example, if you have a command which changes the directory, or assigns a value to a variable, before then executing some other command the result of having a second process is to throw away the execution of the prior command!

Comment: At least your answer avoids the potential lock ups that Serge warns about in his answer.  I'm going to dig into the popen details at some point to figure that out.  So this question still does not have a perfect answer yet...

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take on it (Without having to restart a shell and whatnot)

**Functions:**

- Pipeline redirect (in this example code below acting as a log, but can be used for any other functionality)
- Soft and Hard close of the subprocess
- Background listener

Tested on Windows OS, but should normally also work on Linux.

**Code**

```
import glob
import os
import pathlib
import traceback
import logging
from datetime import datetime
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
from threading import Thread, Event
from typing import Union
from enum import Enum

LOG_FOLDER = "{0}\{1}".format(pathlib.Path().absolute(), "log")
GDB_FOLDER = "C:\\MinGW\\bin"
GDB_EXE = "gdb.exe"
GDB_PY_EXE = "gdb-python27.exe"
CMD_EXE = "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe"
CALC_EXE = "C:\\Windows\\system32\\win32calc.exe"


class LOG_TYPE(Enum):
    Info = 0,
    Warning = 1,
    Error = 2,
    Critical = 3


class STD_LOG(object):
    def __init__(self, name: str, log_enabled: bool = True, print_enabled: bool = True,
                 detailed_log: bool = False) -> None:
        self.log_enabled = log_enabled
        self.print_enabled = print_enabled
        self.filename = "{0}\{1}{2}.log".format(LOG_FOLDER, name,
                                                datetime.now().strftime("-%d_%m_%Y"))  # "-%d_%m_%Y-%H_%M_%S"
        self.logger = logging.getLogger('CLI_LOGGER')
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        handler = logging.FileHandler(filename=self.filename, mode="a", encoding="utf-8")
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
        if detailed_log:
            formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s \t %(name)s \t %(levelname)s: \n%(message)s \n')
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        self.logger.addHandler(handler)

    def output(self, data: str, logtype: LOG_TYPE = LOG_TYPE.Info):
        if not data:
            return None
        if self.print_enabled:
            print(data)
        if self.log_enabled:
            if logtype == LOG_TYPE.Info:
                self.logger.info(msg=data)
            elif logtype == LOG_TYPE.Warning:
                self.logger.warning(msg=data)
            elif logtype == LOG_TYPE.Error:
                self.logger.error(msg=data)
            else:
                self.logger.critical(msg=data)

        # FOR STACKOVERFLOW Example
        # if api_call activated => run api call from a server
        # if output == "desired result":
        #   Do something
        # Etc.

    def input(self, data: str):
        pass
        # FOR STACKOVERFLOW
        # Perhaps a separate log file?
        # Or redirect to output, etc.
        # self.output(data=data)


# inspiration for killable thread -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/49877671
class CLI_THREAD(Thread):
    def __init__(self, source: str, logger: STD_LOG, sleep_interval: float = 0.25) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self._close = Event()
        self._interval = sleep_interval
        self.base = Popen(source, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, text=True, shell=True, close_fds=True)
        self.logger = logger
        self.logger.output(data="CLI STARTED [Process ID: {0}]".format(self.pid()))

    def cli_alive(self) -> Union[bool, int]:
        if self.base.poll() is None:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def pid(self) -> int:
        return self.base.pid

    def run(self) -> None:
        while True:
            try:
                if not self.cli_alive():
                    break

                if self.base.stdout.readable():
                    output = self.base.stdout.readline().strip()
                    self.logger.output(data=output)

                closing = self._close.wait(self._interval)
                if closing and self.base.stdout.closed:
                    break
            except Exception as ex:
                ex_msg = ''.join(traceback.format_exception(None, ex, ex.__traceback__))
                self.logger.output(data=ex_msg, logtype=LOG_TYPE.Error)

        self.logger.output(data="End of CLI Thread")

    def close(self) -> None:
        self._close.set()

    def terminate(self) -> None:
        if self.cli_alive():
            self.base.terminate()
            self.logger.output(data="Terminate function activated", logtype=LOG_TYPE.Warning)


class CLI(object):
    def __init__(self, name: str, source: str, close_arg: str = None, echo: bool = True) -> None:
        self.logger = STD_LOG(name)
        self._cli_thread = CLI_THREAD(source=source, logger=self.logger)
        self._close_arg = close_arg
        self._cli_thread.start()  # start listening to console
        if not echo:
            self.execute("@echo off")

    def close(self):
        if self._close_arg:
            self.execute(command=self._close_arg)
        self._cli_thread.close()

    def cleanup(self):
        self._cli_thread.base.terminate()
        del self._cli_thread

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.cleanup()

    def execute(self, command: str):
        if self._cli_thread.is_alive():
            self._cli_thread.base.stdin.write(command + "\n")
            self._cli_thread.base.stdin.flush()
        else:
            self.logger.output(data="Sending command to CLOSED THREAD", logtype=LOG_TYPE.Error)


def empty_log():
    files = glob.glob("{0}/*".format(LOG_FOLDER))
    for f in files:
        os.remove(f)


def main():
    cli = CLI(name="cli_1", source=CMD_EXE, close_arg="exit")
    try:
        cli.execute(command="cd {0}".format(GDB_FOLDER))
        cli.execute(command=GDB_EXE)
        cli.execute(command="file C:/Windows/system32/win32calc.exe")
        cli.execute(command="quit")
        cli.close()
    except Exception as e:
        msg = ''.join(traceback.format_exception(None, e, e.__traceback__))
        cli.logger.output(data=msg, logtype=LOG_TYPE.Critical)
        cli.cleanup()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    empty_log()
    main()
```

**Output**  (cli-somedate.log)

> CLI STARTED [Process ID: 9720]
> Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.1728] (c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
> C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\ProgramWatcher\src\GDB>cd C:\MinGW\bin
> C:\MinGW\bin>gdb.exe
> GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1 Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc. License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
> This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it. There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
> This GDB was configured as "mingw32". For bug reporting instructions, please see: http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/.
> (gdb) Reading symbols from C:\Windows\system32\win32calc.exe...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
> (gdb) C:\MinGW\bin>exit
> End of CLI Thread

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to do it synchronously if you want to run the commands one after the other, and react / see the output of each before the previous is completed...

As opposed to all other solutions, this one allows you to react/change the flow of your commands as you can parse
the results after each command...

```
import os
import time
import subprocess

p =  subprocess.Popen('bash', stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
         stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, encoding='utf8')
os.set_blocking(p.stdout.fileno(), False)
os.set_blocking(p.stderr.fileno(), False)
#some commands...
cmds = [
    'echo foo',
    'ls',
    'echo bar'
]
i=0
out = ['']
for cmd in cmds:
    p.stdin.write(cmd + "\n")
    p.stdin.write("echo ================\n")
    more_out = []
    while not more_out or more_out[-1]!="================\n":
        p.stdin.flush()
        p.stdout.flush()
        p.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(.01)
        more_out = p.stdout.readlines()
        err = p.stdout.readlines()
        if more_out:
            out.extend(more_out)
            print(''.join(more_out))
        if more_err:
            print('ERROR:', err)
            break
```