# Run commands in new command prompt from a external program run via Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, subprocess

Problem: I need to run an external program from Python which results in a new command prompt and I need to run some commands on the new command prompt.

I have gone through some of the posts related to this:

[Python subprocess - run a second command in the new command prompt created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54887990/python-subprocess-run-a-second-command-in-the-new-command-prompt-created)
[How to run multiple commands synchronously from one subprocess.Popen command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39721924/how-to-run-multiple-commands-synchronously-from-one-subprocess-popen-command)

Even I have tried with os command as:

https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-control-command-prompt-by-using-python-scripts

With

```py
proc = subprocess.Popen(['cli', '--log=cli.log', '--log-level=debug2'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

It seems that 'cli' is running in background and some input is awaited but when I check with ps command, no cli command exist in background and also I get error:

```
tcgetattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

at command line. If I add stderr=subprocess.PIPE, the process gets existed immediately.

Comment: Did you try with `shell=True`?

Comment: Nothing changed even after adding shell=True