# How to write to command line using python

Tags: python, command-prompt

I need to run a series of commands in command prompt and I want to automate this process. I can run a command in command prompt using Python code:

```
import os
os.system("start /B start cmd.exe @cmd /k {command}")
```

OR

```
import os
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["start", "cmd", "/k", "command"], shell = True)
```

However, after executing a command, I cannot write another command to the same command prompt. Is there a way to do this?

The thread
[Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) is similar but I don't think it explains how to write a new command to the same command prompt after the one before finishes executing

Also, as I understand [running multiple bash commands with subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17742789/running-multiple-bash-commands-with-subprocess) explains how to run commands in parallel not one after each other.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [running multiple bash commands with subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17742789/running-multiple-bash-commands-with-subprocess)

Comment: It explains how to run them in parallel not one after another @JD D

Comment: Why using Python, and not any kind of shell script directly? As you may end up having to launch a shell script from Python anyway!?

Comment: You can always run command1; command2; command3... or with & or && if you want to stop on error... depending on your command line shell

Comment: @ToykanOzdeger look at the answer from "admenva", it shows how to run commands one after another.   The answer from "FrancisWolcott" suggests just chaining commands using `&&` which should work for you as well.

Comment: Precision in language really does matter.  What is meant by the phrase "command prompt"? A command prompt is a string that is presented by a shell to the user.  It simply doesn't make any sense to say "run a command in command prompt".  I suppose it means "send a string to a shell for execution", and if you use precise language to describe the problem you are trying to solve I believe the solution becomes trivial.

Answer (score 0):

you can insert the '&' symbol (or other symbols, such as '&&' for example:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["start", "cmd", "/k", "cd Desktop && cd Programs"], shell = True)
```

Comment: I am wondering if there is a guarantee that each function will start after the previous one finishes, in this case.

Comment: `&&` goes one step further. The second command is run only if the first has finished succesfully, i.e. ERRORLEVEL=0, see https://web.archive.org/web/20060412075633/https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score -1):

Popen(["start", "cmd", "/k" "cd Desktop && cd Programs"], shell=True)