# How can i run multiple commands in one subprocces

Tags: python

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['cd/users/Charis Charilaou/desktop/Umbra/Gaming/Minecraft/Minecraft Server/UmbraCraft Test-Server', 'run.bat'] ,shell=True)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [running multiple bash commands with subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17742789/running-multiple-bash-commands-with-subprocess)

Comment: teh most simple way to do what (i assume) you actually want to do is to have something like `SET mypath=%~dp0` followed by `cd %mypath%` at the top of your `run.bat` file. then you can call it directly and it will change to the right folde

start %mypath%\1.4\xiFDR-latest.bat

Comment: For the specific use case of running in a particular directory, simply use the `cwd=` keyword argument of the `subprocess` family of functions.

Comment: how can I do this? (could you send me the code?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the chaining symbol `&&` for that, for example:

`subprocess.Popen(['cd /users/Charis Charilaou/desktop/Umbra/Gaming/Minecraft/Minecraft Server/UmbraCraft Test-Server && bash run.bat'], shell=True)`

Comment: This would work for a Unix-compatible shell, but it looks like the OP is a Windows victim.

Comment: ... Or else they are confused; while the `.bat` extension would generally only work on Windows, their home directory looks like a vaguely Unixy one.