# How to execute commands from a command-line program one after another, if possible, using os or subprocess?

Tags: python, process, subprocess

I wanted to ask if there is a way to run the commands of a command line program in python, but the codes must be executed repeatedly, namely, the solution I want is not this

`os.system(f"xxx.exe {command}").`

I tried subprocess.run function putting the name of the exe  followed by the commands I want to execute inside the brackets and then these keyword args: `stdout=subprocess.PIPE,text=True` however, oddly it doesn't make `data.stdout`  the whole output for some reason. Only the initial code's output is assigned to that. It is probably because the arguments inside the brackets don't represent different lines. Therefore, I guess the thing I've done using subprocess is the same as how I executed a single line of command via the os library.

Namely, my question is using subprocess or os, how can I execute codes that must be executed in different lines, or if not possible, how to execute commands from a command-line program one after another in python?

Edit: Should I make something like this?

```
os.system(f"xxx.exe {command1} \n {command2}")
```

Comment: I assume by the extension `.exe` that you are running in Windows, right? A quick search in google led to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17742789/running-multiple-bash-commands-with-subprocess, which is clearly for Linux. But that's worth a try.

Comment: neither the usage of six quotes works nor putting a semicolon at the end of lines works.

Comment: waitt, what if I operate windows power shell rather than cmd???

Comment: Yesssss, I'm gonna open it as follows: subprocess.run("powershellpath myapppath; command1; command2") thx for help

Comment: Lemme try :) ...

Comment: it doesn't work either since when I open the command line program I can't put semicolon at the end of the lines :(((

Comment: somehow I have to initially launch powershell rather than cmd in subprocess or os

Comment: nope it is gonna result in the same result

Comment: I don't really know what to do :(

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of a shortcut but you could do something like this:

```
import os
import pyautogui

os.startfile('Path_to_command_prompt')

pyautogui.PAUSE = however long it takes to run each command

pyautogui.write('Command_1')
pyautogui.press('enter')

pyautogui.write('Command_2')
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

Comment: I also have to record the output but there may be a way to do so. In order to use this function, it is mandatory to stop what I'm doing. Otherwise, errors may occur. However, apparently, it is the only way :((